# Apex Oracle Application: redirecting to a specific page after sign out

Tags: oracle-apex

Normally when a user sign out from an application, he/she will be redirected back to the login page 9999 (default).

Few minutes ago I created a login page (page10019) but then I deleted because I didn't need it anymore (I thought I do).

Now when I sign in then sign out, it redirects me to page10019 which cause an error to popup to the user saying: `Application "109950" Page "login10019" not found.`

How to change the login page (9999) to the default login page again this way it won't pop-up an error I assume.

I tried to open and search in the application definition and checked the page I'm signing out from and there is no use and couldn't find where I can change this settings.

I tried to open and search in the application definition and checked the page I'm signing out from and there is no use and couldn't find where I can change this settings.

Answer (score 1):

From Shared Components > Authentication Schemes
select the active/current Authentication scheme

Here you should see a tab "Post-Logout URL"

You can define your post-logout URL on this place

Comment: there I have 2 options:
1- Home Page
2- URL

it says: 
Home Page. The Home Link value in the application properties.

where can I find the application properties?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the path as @Uday mentioned, then just place `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.logout?p_this_flow=&APP_ID.&p_next_flow_page_sess=&APP_ID.:<page-id>`.

Or you can also place `f?p=&APP_ID.:<page-id>` directly

Answer (score 0):

That's how it worked for me (thanks for a response in this thread):

From Shared Components > Authentication Schemes select the active/current Authentication scheme > Post-Logout URL:

I chose the second option (URL) and entered the URL from the browser when I run the login page (9999) but without the `?session=#################` from the browser URL.